# How to solve Weapon Target Assignment Variant

Tags: algorithm, math

I am specifically trying to solve this variation:

I have 50 targets, and 1 weapon. The weapon has a certain probability of hitting each target and each target takes a certain amount of time to hit. I only need to hit 1 target successfully in order to succeed, and if I miss 49 targets, I am guaranteed to hit the final target. I am trying to find the order at which to hit targets which will minimize the time required to succeed.

An example with 3 targets:

```
Input: ([time to hit target, numerator of probability, denominator of probability])
targets = [[5, 1, 5], [10, 1, 2], [20, 1, 5]]

Output: (order of targets)
[1, 0, 2]
```

The optimal time is calculated as:

```
T(1,0,2)
= (1/2)(10) + (1 - 1/2)(1/5)(10 + 5) + (1 - 1/2)(1 - 1/5)(20 + 10 + 5)
= 5 + 1.5 + 14 
= 20.5 minutes
```

I have been working on this problem as a fun exercise for a few days now, and can't find a great solution much better than brute force which scales like O(N!).

I am considering a branch and bound algorithm to reduce the cost, but I have not been able to devise a bounding method successfully yet, i.e. how to calculate the minimum possible time and maximum possible time for a given partial order.

Any advice or help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's assume that an order is fixed(somehow). Let's take a closer look at 2 consecutive targets(non of them is the last). Let's say there aiming times are `t1` and `t2` and the probabilities to hit are `p1` and `p2`, respectively. We can see the answer is improved when they are swapped if and only if `p1 * t1 + (1 - p1) * p2 * (t1 + t2) > p2 * t2 + (1 - p2) * p1 * (t1 + t2)`, which means `p2 * t1 > p1 * t2`. Thus, in an optimal answer `p2 * t1 <= p1 * t2`, or `t1 / p1 <= t2 / p2`. This comparator defines an ordering for all elements(we cannot get stuck in a local minimum because the comparator is transitive). However, this holds true if no of the two elements is the last one(because we are guaranteed to hit the last target).

It gives us a simple polynomial solution:

1. Fix the last element(`O(n)` options).
2. Sort the rest of the elements using the comparator described above. Update the answer. This part works in `O(n * log n)` time. Elements with `0` probability should be handled separately(they should be always pushed to the end).

The total time complexity is `O(n^2 * log n)`.